# What was the typical format of a 16th century mathematical debate?

Tags: mathematicians, academia, 16th-century

In *The Equation that Couldn't be Solved*, Mario Livio writes of academia in 16th century Bologna. Apparently, mathematicians would take part in public debates, sometimes involving solving problems. They were extremely well-known, and could result in great discoveries.

What was the format of a mathematical debate? Do any accounts exist of one?

Comment: A good example is the dispute about the method for the solution of the cubic equations, involving [Niccolò Tartaglia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niccol%C3%B2_Fontana_Tartaglia), [Gerolamo Cardano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerolamo_Cardano) and [Scipione del Ferro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scipione_del_Ferro). See [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method).

Comment: You can find the details in many book on history of math, or see : the *Foreword* to : Girolamo Cardano, [Ars Magna or The Rules of Algebra](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZMZY79bvOPgC&printsec=frontcover) (1545 - Dover reprint 1993).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for that. By the way, the cubic dispute inspired this question.

Comment: For a XVII Century case, see : Galileo Galilei & Christoph Scheiner, [On Sunspot](https://books.google.it/books?id=-vz1-geXj8IC&printsec=frontcover) (translated and introduced by Eileen Reeves & Albert Van Helden - 2010)

Comment: Perhaps the most striking difference from modern debate formats was the occasional settling of disputes through [armed combat](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tycho_Brahe#Tycho.27s_nose). :)